# Bind default implementation in case of multiple implementation in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have class hierarchy as follows:

```
interface Pen{}

class SimplePen implements Pen{}

class ComplexPen implements Pen{}
```

Code using this is as follows

```
class A{
  public A(Pen pen){}
} 

class B{
  public B(ComplexPen pen){}
}
```

So what i want to do is, by default Pen should be bound to SimplePen and  ComplexPen should be bound only when asked explicitly as in case of class B.

```
bind(Pen.class).to(SimplePen.class).in(Singleton.class)
bind(ComplexPen.class)
```

The above Guice config fails at runtime saying `implementation of Pen already bound`. How do i go about this?

Note am trying to avoid `.annotatedWith(Names.named("complexPen"))`

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the code i gave works. I had some extra code which was creating more bindings.

```
bind(Pen.class).to(SimplePen.class).in(Singleton.class)
bind(ComplexPen.class)
```